# How to get back to default value in spinner onclick?

Tags: android

My spinner coding is something like this:

```
    assetSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.editAsset);
    assetAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.asset_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    assetAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    assetSpinner.setAdapter(assetAdapter);
```

Now I have a reset button in my design. So my question is when I click on reset button how to make the spinner get back to default value or reset the spinner.

Comment: what do you mean by default value and reset?

Comment: @PareshMayani in our pages we have a submit and reset buttons right..?? so when we click on reset button, generally the edittext fields get cleared... similarly i want to make my spinner get back to its initial position

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can using Spinners [`setSelection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection%28int%29) attribute to reset your Spinner to its original position. `spinner.setSelection(position);`

Comment: u mean i need to keep this in my onclickListener or here itself...??

Comment: you can keep this on your reset button `spinner.setSelection(0);`

Answer (score 12):

by default value, you mean to say the value at 0 index.
Then it should be

```
spinner.setSelection(0);
```

Answer (score 4):

call this thing in your reset on click  event

```
assetSpinner.setSelection(0);
```

Comment: you sure? I dont think, spinner.setSelectedvalue(""); is provided at all.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of my code. I put this in my onCreate():

```
    // Resets all spinners
    Button resetFilters = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
    resetFilters.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageType.setSelection(0);
            colorFilter.setSelection(0);
            imageSize.setSelection(0);
        }
    });
```

It changes all my spinners back to their default position, right before my eyes when button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

spinner.setSelection(position);

this works even in button clicks.

Comment: Hi dreamdeveloper, this looks more like a comment to Lalit Poptani ' s answer?

Comment: this got worked fine for me.just thought of sharing the comment so that people can readily use without confusions. no other intentions. :-)

Comment: Maybe a comment on the existing answer would be better.